# Why can't I mutate this field in a df_tbl?

Tags: r, dplyr

This code:

```
foo <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3))
foo <- foo %>% group_by(x)
foo <- foo %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(x=foo[,'x'])
```

gives this error:

```
Error: not compatible with STRSXP
```

while this line works:

```
foo <- foo %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(x=x)
```

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you mean here. You created a data.frame that has one column and 3 observations, then grouped according to x, immediately un-grouped, and finally used mutate to create (replace) column x with itself. I might be missing something. If you run the following, the error disappears:

```
foo <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3))
foo <- foo %>%
       group_by(x) %>%
       ungroup() %>%
       mutate(x = foo[,'x'])
```

You should use `<-` in R - no offense meant, maybe you are familiar with Python. There are other questions on StackOverflow documenting similar issues. However, in this case I'm not sure we can talk about a "bug". The best part of `dplyr` is that you can pass objects without worrying about quotes. Why would you use that syntax in the first place? Go for:

```
foo <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3))
foo <- foo %>%
       group_by(x) %>%
       ungroup() %>%
       mutate(x = x)
```

It's easier and more intuitive.

Comment: This is all simplified from an actual example to show the error. This code isn't very useful, but the code it came from is.

Comment: Another way to think about this question is: why does grouping and ungrouping produce a weird error? (Again, the actual code has more stuff that makes sense. I use the "weird syntax" because the column name being selected is set from a variable.)